# Solution for Go exercise from "The Go Programming Language" book

Tags: go, bitwise-operators

I've started to read "The Go Programming Language" book and came across to exercice 2.6.2 from chapter 2 about bitwise ops. I don't understand the task totally. So, from book "...PopCount returns the number of setted bits to 1". What is mean? init() function returns this:

```
var pc [256]byte

func init() {
    for i := range pc {
        pc[i] = pc[i/2] + byte(i&1)
        fmt.Printf("%d ", pc[i])
    }
}
```

0 1 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 4 5 5 6 5 6 6 7 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 4 5 5 6 5 6 6 7 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 4 5 5 6 5 6 6 7 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 4 5 5 6 5 6 6 7 4 5 5 6 5 6 6 7 5 6 6 7 6 7 7 8

```
func PopCount(x uint64) int {
    var unit byte
    for i := uint64(0); i < 8; i++ {
        unit += pc[byte(x>>(i*8))]
    }
    return int(unit)
}
```

From book "...uses init() for preliminary calculation table of results for all possible 8-bit values". Please, explain me this operation. And next author writes about 64 steps... What he did mean? What is 64 steps? And argument `x` in PopCount(x) - what it will be demonstrate?

Will be grateful for extended answer!

Comment: popCount is an instruction set-level operation in many processors, which returns the number of 1's in a number's binary representation. For example : binary(2) = 10 => PopCount(2) = 1; binary(7) = 111 => popCount(7) = 3.

Comment: The 8-bit calculation seems to be using init() to pre-calculate the popCount for all 8-bit values in order to save time during future computations.

Answer (score 0):

In Reading about Pop Counts is not very diffcult as your not able to see the two questions are asking about an Array and how to resolve the counts in an 64 bits array you would see how many times you can by an divison with the operation learning the range to calculate the pop counts in the different array fields with basic maths operation for Go Language